# Data fusion pipelines on dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-data-fusion

I will like to execute data fusion pipelines on dataflow. I am currently running data fusion pipelines on data proc. But templating, version control , testing is not possible in  data fusion. So thinking is it possible to run data fusion on dataflow

Comment: Would you like to write a new pipeline to perform the same transformations as your Data Fusion pipeline ? Because, generally speaking,  DataFlow is not a replacement for Data Fusion neither running environment but rather they are complimentary to each other. Data Flow is fully managed by GCP and built on Apache beam (unified programming language). Meanwhile, Data Fusion is based on CDAP (open source pipeline development tool).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Data Fusion does not support running pipeline on Dataflow, only Dataproc and Datasream if you are running an Oracle CDC (replication) pipeline.